# c# event handler on a listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to create an event handler in a listview. I mean I would like to call a function every time I have a new element in my listview. Can someone help me how to do it? I don't need a click event handler. The event handler I would like it to be automatically generated by the code (the ithem from the listview to be selected and then a new method to be called). The element in the listview looks like: `element1 name surname` (this is on the first row). THx

How to create the handler for this function ?

```
private void listview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   for (int x = 0; x < listview1.Items.Count; x++)
   { 
      if (listview1.Items[x].Selected) 
         MessageBox.Show(listview1.Items[x].SubItems[1].Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to create an event handler. Everything I've tried till now didnt work:). So I think the event handler could be the best

Comment: @elisa: C# does not have a listview. The answer will be different for WinForms, WebForms or WPF ListViews.

Comment: listview for WinForms. Thx for understanding.:).

Comment: Hpw to create the handler for this function ? 
private void listview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
 
 for (int x = 0; x < listview1.Items.Count; x++){
 
   if (listview1.Items[x].Selected)
   MessageBox.Show(listview1.Items[x].SubItems[1].Text);
 }
 
}

Comment: @elisa: the posted function _is_ an eventhandler.

Comment: Thx a lot for your suggestion. I'll do that next time:)

Comment: @elisa: you can go to your user page by clicking on your username. There, you will find a list of all your questions and answers. Then go through your old questions and follow Simen S's instructions.

Comment: Thx YOU. Sorry for asking same question twice. I'll not do that anymore:)

Answer (score 3):

As Henk Holterman pointed out, the method you posted in your question, `listview1_SelectedIndexChanged`, IS an event handler. If it's not doing what it's supposed to, that could be because it's not attached to the corresponding event of `listview1`.

If the method already exists in the .cs file containing the code for your form, you need to attach it to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your ListView. To do this, select the control, then click on the lightning icon in the properties panel. Find the event (`SelectedIndexChanged`) in the list, then click on the arrow on the right and select `listview1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

**Update:**

Since you're adding the ListView programatically, you can assign the handler as follows

```
listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += listview1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

As for your crash, I can't really think of anything off the top of my head. Maybe you could post the text of the exception?

Comment: thx for your response. I create a listview programatically. Also the listview items are programatically created and filled. The problem is that I don't know why when I select an element using listview1.SelectedItems[0].Selected = true; Select() the program chashes. The element is not selected.